# probability conditioned on everything

Tags: conditional-probability

what is the probability $\sum_i P(A|B_i)$ given the $\cup_i B_i = \Omega$, where $\Omega$ represents all possible events?

Many thanks,

A.

Comment: Well, probably the answer is not 1, I don't know...

Comment: Where is this coming from? In general it is meaningless to just take a sum of probabilities, because the result might be larger than $1$.

Comment: @fkraiem In an analytic derivation I found many terms like that. I want to assign them a meaning or simplify them even more. Well, after your answer it looks like that sum is not a probability ...